# testng @dataprovider passing multiple class instances

Tags: java, testng

I have this `@DataProvider` defined like this

```
public class A {

@BeforeTest
  @DataProvider(name = "ProvideUsefulClasses")
  public static Object[][] InitiateUsefulClasses() throws MalformedURLException {


      PageObjectOne pageObjOne = new PageObjectOne();
      AndroidDriver driver=pageObjOne.driver;
      TouchAction  touchAction = new TouchAction(driver);
      WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20000);

      return new Object[][] {

          {touchAction, wait},{driver,pageObjOne}


      }  ;
  }
}
```

and I am receiving it like this in a different class

```
@Test(dataProvider = "ProvideUsefulClasses",dataProviderClass=A.class) 
class testMethods {  

    public static TouchAction tAction;
    public static WebDriverWait Wait;
    public static AndroidDriver Driver;
    public static PageObjectOne PageObjectOneInst;

    @Test(priority=1,dataProvider = "ProvideUsefulClasses",dataProviderClass=A.class) 

   public  static void AgreeAllow(Object[][] UsefulClasses) throws InterruptedException{

       tAction = ((TouchAction) UsefulClasses[0][0]);
       Wait= ((WebDriverWait) UsefulClasses[0][1]);

       Driver = ((AndroidDriver) UsefulClasses[1][0]);

       PageObjectOneInst = ((PageObjectOne) UsefulClasses[1][1]);
        ...
        ...
}

}
```

But I receive an error

```
FAILED: AgreeAllow
org.testng.internal.reflect.MethodMatcherException: 
Data provider mismatch
Method: AgreeAllow([Parameter{index=0, type=[[Ljava.lang.Object;, declaredAnnotations=[]}])
Arguments: [(io.appium.java_client.TouchAction)io.appium.java_client.TouchAction@29c5ee1d,(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait)org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait@15cea7b0]
    at org.testng.internal.reflect.DataProviderMethodMatcher.getConformingArguments
```

It seems,by the look of error, I am not receiving or returning data properly , whats missing here?

I want to use `@factory` only if it can not be done this way. 
I haven't tried resolving it using `@factory`, I'll have to search.

**ADDITION:** I found [this](http://testingwarrior.blogspot.com/2015/02/how-to-pass-class-object-through.html) but its only passing one class. How do we do it for multiple classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error is gone when I change the `return` statement to below in `@dataprovider` method

```
return new Object[][] {

          { touchAction, wait,driver,pageObjOne}

      }  ;
```

I also change the definition of receiver method as

```
public  static void AgreeAllow( TouchAction t,WebDriverWait w,AndroidDriver d,PageObjectOne p) throws InterruptedException{

...
...

}
```